# global variable not accessable inside functions

Tags: wordpress, global-variables

I downloaded and installed a wordpress plugin. Everthing works fine on localhost untill i uploaded the site on live server it wasn't working as intended. When i define a variable as global its value is not accessable inside functions.

Courses.php

```
include 'functions.php';
```

functions.php

```
global $PLUGIN_ADDRESS;
echo $PLUGIN_ADDRESS = plugins_url('/', __FILE__);
require 'functions/course.class.php';
```

course.class.php

```
class courses
{
public function course_form($course_edit)
{

     global $PLUGIN_ADDRESS;

     echo $PLUGIN_ADDRESS;
```

and the result is empty. Im getting this $PLUGIN_ADDRESS value correct when i access my site over localhost using the same code. But on live server it returns empty value.

I've also tried using $GLOBALS but still same result.

Any help is highly appericiated.

Thanks

Comment: You shall revise first in php.ini "display_errors = Off" to display_errors = On to see what's the error. In production site, display_errors = Off is by default. After this you do /etc/inid.d/apache2 restart or something else to restart your httpd server.

Comment: thnx for reply. I've enables wordpress define('WP_DEBUG', true); it doesn't show any error.

Comment: It seems that the error comes from the usage of plugins_url() call, if you try $PLUGIN_ADDRESS ="My Plugin Address", it shall work ?

Comment: i tried this already giving some static value. Right after passing the value to global variable, i displayed the variable and it was showing correct value. But when i use the same variable inside the function, its empty.

Comment: $GLOBALS["PLUGIN_ADDRESS"] has so been modified inside the file functions/course.class.php, before lines class courses
{
public function course_form($course_edit)
{... ?

Comment: sorry @jacouh i didn't get you.

Comment: I mean that your may have code before the declaration of "class courses" ?

Comment: nopes. class.course.php has class courses { at line 1. nothing above it.

Comment: Another thinking, you "uploaded" you localhost copy to the remote host, maybe you have installation/configuration problem for plogin_url() function. So plugins_url('/', __FILE__) returns empty ?

Comment: I tried static text for $PLUGIN_ADDRESS = "Plugin address". It doesn't work. I also thought that may be local instalation could be the problem so i uninstalled the plugin on live server and installed it from scratch. Its not just a single variable. There are other variables having the same problem.

Comment: Certainly, you have called it: $xobj = new courses();
$xobj->course_form(""); in Courses.php file.

Comment: I've another file included in Courses.php. include 'codes.php'; and In this file I've called $course = new courses;$course->course_form();

Comment: You have sure pay attention to course_form(), the argument is not optional, should be called ->course_form(""); ?

Comment: argument is required when you are performing edit operation. because same function works for add/edit. I've passed '0' value as argument for add operation. This isn't related to the problem. The problem is global variables not working inside functions.

Comment: I tested you code shown here on Windows PHP5.5, and Linux, all worked. I'm dry without your more code posted for analysis.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Is there anyway i could send you the files for analysis?

Comment: If not too sensitive (hide your personal elements), you could put more in this page ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39163/discussion-between-aaqib-iqbal-and-jacouh)

Comment: STILL HAVEN'T FOUND THE SOLUTION...